# Return to application after call is cancelled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiapplication, telprompt

I want to use `telprompt://` scheme to return to my application after it makes a call. But I have a problem.

If remote person is busy two buttons are shown to me: Redial and Cancel. So if I press Cancel I won't return to my application. Is there any way to handle it?

P. S. Isn't `telprompt://` in Private API?

Answer (score 1):

Here You can Use the WebView and Load Request on it.

```
 UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];   
 NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber]
 [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

I am Sure It would work with Charm.....

Comment: Nothing happens. Absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",num]]];
```